# items not scrolling in flet gui

Tags: python, flet

I created a gui using `flet` and added `ft.ScrollMode.AUTO`
but its still not scrolling when I try to scroll this is my code:

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
 checkboxes_tab = ft.Tab(
        text="Checkboxes",
        content=ft.Column([
            ft.Checkbox(label='item1', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item2', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item3', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item4', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item5', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item6', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item7', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item8', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item9', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item10', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item11', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item12', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item13', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item14', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item15', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item16', value=True),
            ft.Checkbox(label='item17', value=True),

        ],ft.ScrollMode.AUTO)
    )
 tabs = ft.Tabs(
        selected_index=0,
        tabs=[ checkboxes_tab]
    )

 page.add(tabs)

ft.app(target=main)
```

Its suppose to scroll up and down when I scroll using the scroll wheel/trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

The items are not scrolling because the tab is not limited in height and `ft.ScrollMode.AUTO` is not parsed exactly.

There are two ways to limit the height, either set the height at some value or set expand to 1 (like the example [here](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/tabs)). `ft.ScrollMode.AUTO` needs exact parsing: `scroll=ft.ScrollMode.AUTO`

A slightly modified version of your code that scrolls:

```
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    checkboxes_tab = ft.Tab(
        text="Checkboxes",
        content=ft.Column(
            [
                ft.Checkbox(label="item1", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item2", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item3", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item4", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item5", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item6", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item7", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item8", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item9", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item10", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item11", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item12", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item13", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item14", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item15", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item16", value=True),
                ft.Checkbox(label="item17", value=True),
            ],
            scroll=ft.ScrollMode.AUTO,
        ),
    )
    tabs = ft.Tabs(selected_index=0, tabs=[checkboxes_tab], expand=1)

    page.add(tabs)


ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: oh thanks but when I add buttons on top it stops working
(code is too long so using paste bin)
 https://pastebin.com/FiX8tk0Z

Comment: because scroll is not set for ft.Column in the code with buttons

Answer (score 0):

Under the `def main(page: ft.Page):` put `page.scroll = ft.ScrollMode.ALWAYS`